# A question of Cor2.14 on Hatcher's textbook

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let  $\overset{\sim}{H}_{i} (X)$ be a reduced homology. I do not catch a precise reason why

> $\overset{\sim}{H}_{i}(S^n)=0$ holds if $ i \neq n $.

holds.

According to the textbook, mathematical induction is used and using the prop2.6, prop2.8

> **Prop2.6** Corresponding to a decomposition of a space $X$ into its path component $X_{\alpha}$ there is an isomorphism of $H_n(X)$ with
> the direct sum $\bigoplus _{\alpha} H_n(X_{\alpha}). $
>
> **prop2.8** If $X$ is a point, then $H_n(X)=0$ for $n>0$ and $H_0(X)=
> > \mathbb{Z} $

Here is my sketch :
if $n=0$, it is true because $0= H_{i}(S^0)=\overset{\sim}{H}_{i} (S^0)$. And then suppose $H_{i}(S^{k})=0  $ holds when $n=k$. Then, it seems to finish when $n=k+1$ holds. But I cannot apply  **prop2.6** to given proof.

According to my guess, $S^{k+1}$ seems to decompose some path components. Thus, $\overset{\sim}{H}_{i}(S^{k+1})=\overset{\sim}{H}_{i}(*) \oplus \overset{\sim}{H}_{i}(S^k) $ and, since both components expected to be $0$ (the first component is unknown but cleary should be $0$ and the second component is clearly $0$ from the previous assumption)

Furthermore, I have also a question about why **Prop2.8** is used during the proof. This seems to be needed when I try to verify the case $n=0$, but I don't see why this proposition is used.

Even though my sketch seems to be thoroughly wrong, this is the trial that I do my best. Anyway, I want to know why $\overset{\sim}{H}_{i}(S^n)=0$ holds if $ i \neq n $ holds.

Comment: $\Bbb S^n$ is connected, hence consists of precisely one path component. You can however write it as the union of two hemispheres, which leads to an application of Mayer Vietoris…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hatcher's proof sketch, Propositions 2.6 and 2.8 are for proving the $n=0$ case. First, we need to recognize that $S^0$ is just a set of two points. Applying Prop 2.6 (splitting homology by path components) to it tells us that $H_i(S^0) = H_i(\mathrm{pt}) \oplus H_i(\mathrm{pt})$. Proposition 2.8 tells us the homology of a point, so $H_0(S^0) = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H_i(S^0) = 0$ when $i\neq 0$. Finally following Hatcher's comments after his definition of reduced homology groups, you can see that $\tilde{H}_0(S^0) = \mathbb{Z}$.

For the induction step, you apply Theorem 2.13 to the pair $(D^n, S^{n-1})$ as Hatcher specifies. The key ideas are that if you quotient out the boundary of a disc, you get a sphere, and that a disc is contractible. This is a common proof technique in algebraic topology. Constructing an LES involving some contractible spaces tells us that the corresponding terms in the LES are zero. Here the LES for the pair $(D^n, S^{n-1})$ looks like
$$
\cdots\to \tilde{H}_i(D^n)\to \tilde{H}_i(D^n/S^{n-1})\cong \tilde{H}_i(S^n) \to \tilde{H}_{i-1}(S^{n-1})\to \tilde{H}_{i-1}(D^n)\to\cdots
$$
Notice that since $\tilde{H}_i(D^n)=\tilde{H}_{i-1}(D^n)=0$, the LES just breaks up into isomorphisms $\tilde{H}_i(S^n)\to \tilde{H}_{i-1}(S^{n-1})$. This is the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** use [Mayer Vietoris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence) on the decomposition of $\Bbb S^n$ into the upper and lower hemispheres $\Bbb D^n_+$ and $\Bbb D^n_-$. Note that the hemispheres are contractible (homotopy equivalent to the point) and intersect in the equator, a $\Bbb S^{n-1}$. So apply induction and your theorem 2.8.

**Edit** Of cause there are several ways to deduce the desired result. According to Elliot Yu‘s answer Hatcher uses excission, because Mayer Vietoris is only introduced later. I did not check that, apologies for possible inconveniences.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me! I find Mayer Vietoris easier to work with than excission and thought it would be introduced earlier, but failed to check this assumption…

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment before you had a chance to post the response. I saw your edit as soon as I posted, so I removed the comment since it became clear that you realized what I was going to say.

Comment: No worries. Anyway thanks for the clarification :)